# Debugging strategy for a bug (apparently) affected by timing

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm fairly inexperienced with python, so I find myself at a loss as to how to approach this bug. I've inherited a python app that mainly just copies files and folders from one place to another. All the files and folders are on the local machine and the user has full admin rights, so there are no networking or security issues here.

What I've found is that a number of files fail to get copied from one directory to another unless I slow down the code somehow. If I just run the program it fails, but if I step through with a debugger or add `print` statements to the copy loop, it succeeds. The difference there seems to be either the timing of the loop or moving things around in memory.

I've seen this sort of bug in compiled languages before, and it usually indicates either a race condition or memory corruption. However, there is only one thread and no interaction with other processes, so a race condition seems impossible. Memory corruption remains a possibility, but I'm not sure how to investigate that possibility with python.

Here is the loop in question. As you can see, it's rather simple:

```
def concat_dirs(dir, subdir):
    return dir + "/" + subdir

for name in fullnames:
    install_name = concat_dirs(install_path, name)
    dirname = os.path.dirname(install_name)
    if not os.path.exists(dirname): 
        os.makedirs(dirname)
    shutil.copyfile(concat_dirs(java_path, name), install_name)
```

That loop usually fails to copy the files unless I either step through it with a debugger or add this statement after the `shutil.copyfile` line.

```
    print "copied ", concat_dirs(java_path, name), " to ", install_name
```

If I add that statement or step through in debug, the loop works perfectly and consistently. I'm tempted to say "good enough" with the `print` statement but I know that's just masking an underlying problem.

I'm not asking you to debug my code because I know you can't; I'm asking for a debug strategy. How do I approach finding this bug?

Comment: Does python raise any errors, or is it just that the files do not get copied?

Comment: What is concat_dirs?  Why not just use os.path.join?  What is in that function?

Comment: If it really is a timing issue (and not that calling `concat_dirs` an extra time modifies something that makes a difference), then one possible strategy is that you can speed up your logging considerably by just appending a string or two to some list of log messages somewhere. Print them out later once the bad behavior has occurred (if it does).

Comment: Also, is `dfcenv.java_path` the same as `java_path`?

Comment: @ebarr - Python raises no errors. The files simply don't get copied. And `dfcenv.java_path` should have been simply `java_path`. That was a typo on my part when I simplified the code for posting.

Comment: I suspect `concat_dirs`.  Some debugging steps I'd do are 1) replace that print call with a `time.sleep(.1)` to see if it is indeed timing and 2) use external tools to monitor the directory for file system events (presumably python is doing *something*, it's just the wrong thing).  I could tell you exactly how to do that in *nix but I don't know off the top of my head how it's done in windows.

Comment: I've edited the question and added `concat_dirs`.

Comment: @roippi Good idea. I'll try your suggestion tomorrow to see if it's really just timing. I know how to monitor file system events on Windows and I've already determined the files simply aren't being written.

Comment: @CareyGregory Please follow up when you get this figured out, would you? I'm really curious about the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

You *do* have a race condition: you check for the existence of dirname and then try to create it. That *should* cause the program to bomb if something unexpected happens, but...

In Python, we says that it's easier to ask forgiveness than permission. Go ahead and create that directory each time, then apologize if it already exists:

```
import errno
import os

for name in fullnames:
    source_name = os.path.join(java_path, name)
    dest_name = os.path.join(install_path, name)
    dest_dir = os.path.dirname(dest_name)

    try:
        os.makedirs(dest_dir)
    except OSError as exc:
        if exc.errno != errno.EEXIST:
            raise

    shutil.copyfile(source_name, dest_name)
```

I'm not sure how I'd troubleshoot this, other than by trying it the non-racy way and seeing what happens. There may be a subtle filesystem issue that's making this run oddly.

Comment: I would be surprised if this was what was causing the issue. If there is only one thread and this is the only process using these directories this issue should be irrelevant (although it is the pythonic way of doing things).

Comment: @ebarr I'm skeptical too, but nothing else stands out. I'm wondering if it's a Windows cache flushing thing, particularly if the destination is on a network share.

Comment: +1 for the good general Python advice, and I've implemented it throughout the code, but I'm afraid it doesn't solve the problem.